# Inappropriate Downloading Notification. How to remove?

Tags: downloading, notification-bar, android-versions

I had installed a Hindi Dictionary Application which contains the Speech to Text Output.After pressing the speech button then the Downloading notification came up,three days passed still the notification isn't cleared any way to handle it.[Please Check Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8TZd.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the data and cache of the app:

The steps depend on phone make and Android version:

Touch and hold the notification > Touch the 'i', it will bring you to the app (Downloader Manager) > Clear Data and Cache and you're done.

On Samsung J5, Marshmallow (6.0.1)

- Touching an app notification: 
  [image]
- Touching the i symbol:
  [image]
- Touching Storage option:
  [image]

Comment: ,There is no option to clear data there.

Comment: There should be. What do you see after touching the i ?

Comment: The option of Force stop and Go to App are able to press but clear Data not

Comment: If you won't get my response then I can send a pic

Comment: Do you see Storage? (The first option)

Comment: Storage in setting?

Comment: Not in Settings, in where touching the i symbol leaded you

Comment: Block,Priority and Sensitive option are there

Comment: On pressing the i button

Comment: I dragged the App to App info to Clear Data

Comment: Did you solve your issue? The aim was to clear data and cache. Steps was just different depending on phone and Android version.

Comment: Yup but the popup still there no change

Comment: What app showed up in App info?

Comment: In App Info it showed only Force Stop and Go to App option to work and rest clear data and cache were not pressable

Comment: Kindly help me.Any other way?

Comment: Check the update.